# Deleted Bootcamp partition space is not unavailable anymore

Tags: macos, bootcamp, catalina, disk-space

I uninstalled windows 10 I had installed using the bootcamp assistant, after which my MacOS disk size hasn't restored to normal. How do I reclaim the lost space?
[image: Output of the command 'diskutil list']

Comment: There's some double negative going in the title. Are you basically asking how to remove disk0s3 and put that space back allocated to Container Disk 1 - disk0s2? I think that's the first step - then someone can ask about what you want the makeup of synthesized disk 1 to be. There might be three questions here, but I wanted to be sure you're looking to one step first before jumping in with a possible answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a strange configuration. The drive's `disk0s3` is type APFS in the GUID Partition Table (GPT), but does not appear to be APFS formatted. This would explain why the Boot Camp Assistant failed. Hopefully, these commands will fix your problem.

```
sudo diskutil apfs deletecontainer -force disk0s3
sudo diskutil erasevolume free none disk0s3
sudo diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0
```

Comment: +1 Thanks very much, and sorry for late reply, it worked well and I have my disk fixed, cheers!